# linear transfomation

Tags: vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Definition-A

Let $V$ be a vector space over a field $F$, then the mapping $T: V \rightarrow V $ is called linear transformation if the following conditions are satisfied.
(i) $T(x+y)=T(x)+T(y)$ (ii) $ T(\alpha x)= \alpha T(x)$

Definition-B

Let $V$ be a vector space over a field $F$, then mapping $T: V \rightarrow V $ is called linear transformation if 
 $T(\alpha x+\beta y)=\alpha T(x)+\beta T(y)$

Question is some authors use definition-A and others use definition-B. Whether both of them are equivalent. Clearly Definition-A implies definition-B. How to prove definition-B implies definition-A?

Answer (score 1):

To get $(i)$ put $\alpha=\beta=1$ and to get $(ii)$ put $\alpha=1, \beta=0.$

Comment: Assume that V is semigroup with respect to addition and F is semiring without multiplicative identity 1. Then is it  possible?

Comment: Well...Without $1$  my proof becomes incorrect

Comment: Dear Mr. Leox  Thank for your proof and comments . So  A implies B always true, but another one need not be true in general am I right ?

Comment: I think that for semigroups you may use the definition B and forget the definition A

Comment: Yes it is good idea thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

$T(\alpha x+ \beta y) = T(\alpha x) + T (\beta y) = \alpha T(x) + \beta T(y)$.